# how to reduce contrast and saturation to make text over a photo more visible

Tags: gimp

I used a photo for a book cover and have to place text on the photo.

To improve visibility of the text, I want to reduce contrast and saturation in the area around the text (but not for other parts) of the photograph.

[image]

What is the best approach with GIMP?

I plan to add a layer with regions slightly bigger than the text areas and then make it less transparent and put this layer below the text but above the photo.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1):

- Make a selection around your text with some margin(about a character's height)(*)
- `Select>Feather` by about the margin width
- Add a transparent layer, fill the section with gray (RGB(127,127,127))
- Move the layer under your text
- Set the layer to `Screen` mode
- Adjust of the gray layer opacity to taste

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are probably manys way you could do it, but probably best to keep it really simple. Anyway, try this:

1. Add a new transparent layer under the text layer
2. Draw a rectangle using the rectangle select tool
3. Press <kbd>D</kbd> to set the default black foreground and white background colours.
4. Do *Edit > Fill with BG colour*, then reduce the layer opacity in the layers panel (shown highlighted red below).

[image]

Example

Comment: sounds exactly like what I need. Thank you for clear explanation! will try a bit later...